# Silverlight applet (<object> tag) not located within its containing <div> tag`

Tags: html, css, silverlight

I've got a Silverlight applet whose UI consists of nothing more than a single button, which I'm trying to located in an appropriate position on my web page. My current result looks like this:

[image: Current Results]

The blue element circled in red is where I want the button to be, and as the Firebug highlight shows, it's where the `<div>` tag containing the Silverlight `<object>` tag is positioned. However, the object itself (the "Click Me" button circled in green) is about 200 or so pixels lower.

My CSS is kinda complex (not unexpectedly, what I'm trying to do is a lot more complex than what I can show here), but for the record, it's here, reasonably simplified:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Engagement Test Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div.alantaHost
        {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
        }

        div.alantaEngageHost
        {
        }

        div.alantaEngageAppHost
        {
            position: relative;
        }
        div.alantaEngageHost_Button
        {
            height: 26px;
            width: 140px;
        }

        button.alantaEngageButton
        {
            position: relative;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: large;
        }

        div.alantaEngageAppHost_Button
        {
            height: 26px;
            width: 140px;
        }
        /* Override */
        div.alantaHost_PictureButton
        {
            width: 220px;
            border: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            background-color: #fff;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            box-shadow: 8px 8px 11px #888;
            border-radius: 8px;
        }

        /* Override */
        div.alantaEngageHost_PictureButton
        {
        }

        div.alantaHeader
        {
            width: 220px;
            height: 18px;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin-top: 4px;
        }

        div.alantaTitle
        {
            margin-left: 10px;
            float: left;
        }

        div.alantaContact
        {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 4px;
            padding: 5px;
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            text-align: left;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        img.alantaContactImage
        {
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
        }

        div.alantaStartChat
        {
            width: 210px;
            height: 30px;
            margin: 0px 4px;
        }

        button.alantaStartChatButton
        {
            position: relative;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: large;
        }

        div.alantaHost_Ad
        {
            width: 300px;
            height: 250px;
        }

        div.alantaContact_Ad
        {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            float: left;
        }

        div.alantaStartChat_Ad
        {
            width: 75px;
            height: 60px;
            float: right;
        }

        div.alantaAdMessage
        {
            width: 80px;
            float: right;
            text-align: left;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        div.alantaEngageAppHost_Ad
        {
            height: 60px;
            width: 70px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="host">
        <div class="alantaHost alantaHost_PictureButton alantaHost_Ad">
            <div style="display: block;" class="alantaEngageHost alantaEngageHost_PictureButton">
                <div class="alantaHeader">
                    <div class="alantaTitle">
                        Ken Smith</div>
                </div>
                <div class="alantaContact alantaContact_Ad">
                    <img class="alantaContactImage" src="http://graph.facebook.com/739004749/picture?type=large"
                        alt="Photo"></div>
                <div class="alantaStartChat alantaStartChat_Ad" align="center">
                    <button style="display: none;" class="alantaEngageButton">
                        Talk to Ken</button></div>
                <div class="alantaAdMessage">
                    I'm looking forward to talking with you!</div>
            </div>
            <div style="top: 2px; left: 224px;" class="alantaEngageAppHost alantaEngageAppHost_Button alantaEngageAppHost_Ad">
                <object type="application/x-silverlight" data="data:application/x-silverlight," id="objMyApp"
                    height="100%" width="100%">
                    <param name="source" value="http://app.dev.alanta.com/ClientBin/SilverlightButton.xap">
                </object>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions about why the Silverlight object isn't following its containing tag? (I should note that it behaves the same way in IE and in Chrome, so it's not a browser bug.)

Comment: What does your silverlight xaml file look like?

Comment: Nothing special. My goal is to get it to work with a very complex app, but for the purposes of this test, I'm using a Silverlight app that has nothing more than a single page, with a single button on it, and no other code (i.e., the button does nothing when clicked).

Comment: I also just tried replacing the Silverlight applet with a standard HTML button, and the HTML button behaves exactly the same way. (Shoulda tried that earlier.) Is there some sort of weird rule about how HTML elements behave when their parents are floated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't understand all the details about what was tripping it up, but it may have had something to do with the fact that I wasn't setting the height of the alantaEngageHost. I changed the alantaEngageHost_Ad style to this:

```
div.alantaEngageHost_PictureButton
{
    height: 250px;
}
```

And after that, the `<button>` and its containing `<div>` tag were in the same place; and I could then place them appropriately like so:

```
<div style="top: -226px; left: 224px;" class="alantaEngageAppHost alantaEngageAppHost_Button alantaEngageAppHost_Ad">
    <button style="position:relative">HTML Button</button>
</div>
```

I'm guessing that there must be some weird CSS interaction that shows up when you're trying to position elements inside a `<div>` tag that isn't quite big enough to contain them. Just a guess, as CSS remains a dark and sorcerous art to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the offsets in your xaml are pushing the button to that location.  If your root element is a canvas I would change that to a stackpanel and see if that fixes it.

Comment: As it turns out, it didn't have anything to do with Silverlight. I replaced the `<object>` tag with a `<button>` tag, and it behaved the same way. Shoulda checked that first . . .